# QgsMarkerLineSymbolLayerV2 change default marker

Tags: pyqgis, svg, markers

I am trying to use the QgsMarkerLineSymbolLayerV2 line symbol layer in my app. I can only make it work using default circle as marker as below:

```
layer1 = QgsMarkerLineSymbolLayerV2(True, 3)
```

how do you change the marker from the default circle to a say, star (*)? Also, can I use a svg marker at all?